# Video stuttering when gaming

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I have a very powerful gaming laptop, and I used to play all games just fine on ultra.
 But now when I enter any games, it stutters, and its a really weird stutter (it's only the camera that stutters.  The environment runs smooth, but when I move the camera it's stuttering big time.)

The stutter appears in any game I play, even games that don't require any GPU or CPU.
I have tried to switch my mouse to see if it's a mouse problem, but its doesn't appear to be.

The stutter appears mostly in Skyrim, even at low settings)

If there is any other information that is needed, please let me know.

**PC specs**
CPU: Intel core i7 -3630QM
GPU: nvidia GeForce GTC 675M / 2GB GDDR5
RAM: 8GB

Comment: Have you tried running with the latest drivers?  My old gaming laptop ran terrible on the "stock" drivers from the laptop manufacturer, I had to (force) install OEM drivers to get it working even barely well.

Comment: Hey, @Rusty.  I've changed the word lag to stutter, as I suspect that's what you're meaning.  Does the game twitch a lot, while you can still hear the sound just fine?  When you don't move the camera, does the environment animate smoothly, or does that stutter, too?

Comment: with a powerful gaming laptop you usually get a big fan. Have you checked that the fan/internals arn't full of dust? subsequently causing your pc to heat up and your performance to suffer due to self throttling hardware?

Comment: Have you installed any other software on your computer lately? specifically those that run as a service or in the background? Competing for system resources is usually a common reason for a program stutter.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling the game? possibly a corrupt game resource file of some sort.

Comment: Are you using a wireless mouse? Usually, when the camera stutters (which is controlled by the mouse), it's because of some wireless interference or weak batteries. I had the same issue on my desktop and fixed that by plugging my Bluetooth adapter to my PC using a long USB cable with the adapter sitting now on my desk right in front of my mouse.

Comment: I agree with Nolonar, that sounds like an issue with the mouse.

Comment: latest drivers installed.

Comment: 1.latest drivers installed.  
2.when i don't move the camera everything is fine, the sound too.  
3.i bought the computer with th most poweful on it could carry.  
4.the only thing that runs is the background is programs that comes with windows normaly.  
5. i have reinstalled every game, and its still the same.
6. i use a wireless mouse yes, but i have tried with the touchpad on the computer aswell (same result)

Comment: Have you tried changing the mouse sensitivity? If it's very high it can jump around a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed nvidia released a driver update and now it works. Thanks for the answers anyway

Answer (score 1):

Could be a lot of problems.
Try some of these...
1) Update Drivers
2) Roll-back Drivers if there was no updates when you tried number one 
3) check if the laptop is hot, if it is very hot that is bad and i would recommend taking it to a professional that can give you a diagnostic.
4)  Turn off V-Sinc

Other than those 4 options i'm afraid i know not that problem.